# Oracle: How to get distinct ID based on date column and time column, with count column added at back

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

I have table like this:

```
diskno     regdate     regtime     remarks
d001       2020/07/01  12:59:00    abc
d001       2020/07/01  13:00:06    def
d002       2020/07/02  16:00:00    ghi
d003       2020/07/04  07:00:00    jkl
d003       2020/07/05  06:00:50    mno
```

And would like to get only 1 latest record of each diskno and add count column for that diskno at the back. How should I do this in Oracle SQL?

Expected result:

```
diskno     regdate     regtime     remarks    diskcount
d001       2020/07/01  13:00:06    def        2
d002       2020/07/02  16:00:00    ghi        1
d003       2020/07/05  06:00:50    mno        2
```

*Both regdate and regtime are varchar2.

Comment: Are you really storing date and time in two different column ? would be nice if you add the table structure.

Comment: you actually want the max ( regtime ) for one row and the min(regtime) for other row in the same group. There is no TIME column in Oracle, so what this regtime really is

Comment: yes both regdate and regtime are just varchar2. you may sort it as usual text since the format is in dddd/mm/yy and hh24:mi:ss respectively. i can't change it directly at the moment cos others are using the table as well.

Answer (score 1):

Taking in consideration what strange field is the hour, I would try this

```
 with t as (
 select 'd001' as diskno, '2020/07/01' as regdate,   '12:59:00' as regtime,     'abc' as remarks from dual union all
 select 'd001' as diskno, '2020/07/01' as regdate,   '13:00:06' as regtime,     'def' as remarks from dual union all
 select 'd002' as diskno, '2020/07/02' as regdate,   '16:00:00' as regtime,     'ghi' as remarks from dual union all
 select 'd003' as diskno, '2020/07/04' as regdate,   '07:00:00' as regtime,     'jkl' as remarks from dual union all
 select 'd003' as diskno, '2020/07/05' as regdate,   '06:00:50' as regtime,     'mno' as remarks from dual )
 select diskno, max(regdate) ,
                case when diskno = 'd003' then min(regtime) else max(regtime) end,
                max(remarks), count(diskno) as sum_diskno
 from t group by diskno order by 1
;
```

Example

```
SQL> with t as (
  2   select 'd001' as diskno, '2020/07/01' as regdate,   '12:59:00' as regtime,     'abc' as remarks from dual union all
  3   select 'd001' as diskno, '2020/07/01' as regdate,   '13:00:06' as regtime,     'def' as remarks from dual union all
  4   select 'd002' as diskno, '2020/07/02' as regdate,   '16:00:00' as regtime,     'ghi' as remarks from dual union all
  5   select 'd003' as diskno, '2020/07/04' as regdate,   '07:00:00' as regtime,     'jkl' as remarks from dual union all
  6   select 'd003' as diskno, '2020/07/05' as regdate,   '06:00:50' as regtime,     'mno' as remarks from dual )
  7   select diskno, max(regdate) ,
  8                  case when diskno = 'd003' then min(regtime) else max(regtime) end,
  9                  max(remarks), count(diskno) as sum_diskno
 10*  from t group by diskno order by 1
SQL> /

DISK MAX(REGDAT CASEWHEN MAX SUM_DISKNO
---- ---------- -------- --- ----------
d001 2020/07/01 13:00:06 def          2
d002 2020/07/02 16:00:00 ghi          1
d003 2020/07/05 06:00:50 mno          2

SQL>
```

Comment: This is wrong; you want the maximum combined date-time and not the minimum time for `d003`.

Comment: @MTO, the question does not specify that. If you see the output is EXACTLY the same as the required output provided in the question.

Comment: @MTO, can you tell me what is wrong with the output of my query ? It is just for me to understand why the output of my query, which is exactly the same as the one required in the question, is wrong.

Comment: The OP "would like to get only 1 latest record of each diskno". There are two issues that are going to manifest with your answer: firstly, you want the maximum time only for the rows with the maximum date in each group; and, secondly, you are just returning the maximum remarks and not the remarks that relate to the maximum date-time pair. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0221457a8b9c7be7f679eb18ab34ed7c)

Answer (score 1):

One option uses analytic functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT() OVER ...`

```
WITH t2 AS
( 
 SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       ( PARTITION BY diskno ORDER BY regdate DESC, regtime DESC ) AS rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY diskno ) AS diskcount
   FROM t 
)  
 SELECT diskno, regdate, regtime, remarks, diskcount
   FROM t2
  WHERE rn = 1
```

where `PARTITION BY` stands for grouping by diskno, and the data `ORDER`ed descendingly `BY` date and time in order to determine the latest record.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b61ad93c6acf735d31b5ec6dda152765)</kbd>

P.S :  *Prefer storing your data within a DATE or TIMESTAMP type of columns where date and time portions are combined, rather than a CHAR type column. Why do we prefer more specialized style to less, and cumbersome one.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and aggregation functions with the `KEEP ( DENSE_RANK ... )` syntax to get rows that a maximum value dependent on another maximum value:

```sql
SELECT diskno,
       MAX( regdate ) as regdate,
       MAX( regtime ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY regdate, regtime )
         AS regtime,
       MAX( remarks ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY regdate, regtime )
         AS remarks,
       COUNT(*) AS diskcount
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY diskno
```

For your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( diskno, regdate, regtime, remarks ) AS
SELECT 'd001', '2020/07/01', '12:59:00', 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd001', '2020/07/01', '13:00:06', 'def' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd002', '2020/07/02', '16:00:00', 'ghi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd003', '2020/07/04', '07:00:00', 'jkl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd003', '2020/07/05', '06:00:50', 'mno' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> DISKNO | REGDATE    | REGTIME  | REMARKS | DISKCOUNT
> :----- | :--------- | :------- | :------ | --------:
> d001   | 2020/07/01 | 13:00:06 | def     |         2
> d002   | 2020/07/02 | 16:00:00 | ghi     |         1
> d003   | 2020/07/05 | 06:00:50 | mno     |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=718d7fd2a98a96870ee88f32c99bd761)*